# Catch all email forwarding from Heroku

Tags: email, heroku, paas

I'm considering moving from a traditional webhost (with CPanel) to Heroku.  Will I be able to match my current hosts capability to catch all email to my domain and forward it to my GMail account?

Perhaps my assumptions are off base about the DNS side of this, but I assume there is some way to have my entire *example.com* domain hosted on heroku, and therein handle web traffic, email traffic, etc.

**How can I set up a Heroku site to catch and forward all email to another address?**

Heroku has several email related add-ons available (http://addons.heroku.com/#email-sms), but they seem to be all about email/app integration, which I don't need.  Do I even need an add-on for this or is there some built in setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku itself does not provide email hosting/sending.

Sending email from your applications is achieved using a third party addon such as SendGrid/Mailgun etc. If you wish to receive email on your domain you would need to find an email hosting provider (eg Google Apps) and configure you MX (Mail Exchange) DNS records to deliver messages to them whilst your CNAME entries would be configured to point at Heroku

Comment: Thank you... the MX record in DNS is the part I was missing.  So I *can* route email to one server and web traffic to another at the DNS level.